# Require and overwrite module scoped variable for testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I have a module like this:

```
var hello = 'Hello Sir'

console.log(hello)
```

I would like to require the module in another file, to `rewire` it, but when I do it will execute hello world. Is there any way to rewire a module before it's executed?

#### `babel-plugin-rewire` attempt

```
var g = require('./global.js')
g.__Rewire__('hello', 'Hello Madam')
```

Because this uses `require` and doesn't export anything, this just executes, and `g` has no value.

#### `proxyquire` attempt

It seems that `proxyquire` will allow me to alter the global `hello` variable, but only if I covert it into a module call.

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire')
proxyquire('./global', {'./hello': 'Hello Madam'})
```

#### `sandboxed-module` attempt

This module seems to have the ability to set `globals` and `locals`, but not overwrite existing values in the module.

```
const SandboxedModule = require('sandboxed-module')
SandboxedModule.require('./global', {
  globals: {hello: 'hello Madam'}
})
```

Comment: not without manually manipulating the source before it is evaluated.

Comment: usually the part `console.log(hello)` is inside a function, in which case just using the npm rewire module will work the way you want

Comment: @Catalyst Yeah the requirement is that the file / module will execute code. I am interested in using something that injects the variable and is a replacement for `require`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to dynamically change "Hello Sir" to "Hello World" at runtime, after the module has been read, is that right?

One approach is to read in the module as plain text, not using `require`, and use a tool like [recast](https://github.com/benjamn/recast) to convert it into an [Abstract-Syntax Tree](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/335141/understanding-abstract-syntax-trees-in-compilers).

Once it's an AST, you can modify it in any way you prefer, and execute dynamically using eval.

*hello.js*

```
var hello = 'Hello Sir'

console.log(hello)
```

*recast.js*

```
const recast = require("recast");
const fs = require('fs');

// read the file in as plain text
const code = fs.readFileSync('./hello.js');

// create abstract syntax tree
const ast = recast.parse(code);

// change value of the first variable
ast.program.body[0].declarations[0].init.value = 'Hello World';

// convert AST back to Javascript text
const modifiedSrc = recast.print(ast).code;

// execute modified code
eval(modifiedSrc);
```

*executing from the command line*

```
~/example$ node recast.js
Hello World
```

Comment: This could work. It is a pain though. I am looking for something that behaves similar to the tools above, and will also read out for the testing coverage report a percentage for the file. Using eval would definitely mess that up.